# How to add enum for attribute so that it comes as dropdown in swagger ui using spring webflux,openapi 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am writing a reactive application using webflux with springdoc-openapi(v 1.4.3). Below is the router class

```
@Configuration
public class AppRouter {
  @RouterOperation(path = "/app", produces = {
      MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
      beanClass = Apphandler.class, method = RequestMethod.GET, beanMethod = "getApp",
      operation = @Operation(operationId = "getApp", responses = {
          @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "successful operation",
              content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = AppResponse.class)))
      },
          parameters = {
              @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.HEADER, name = "Authorization ",required = true),
              @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "id",required = true),
              @Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "idType")
              
      }
      ))
  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(Apphandler handler) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/app"), handler::getApp);
  }

}
```

Corresponding to above api definition below swagger response is coming
[image]

pom contains the below dependency for openapi

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Below queries:

Q1. I have made id and authorization as required=true but even when I am running without providing them from swagger it is not giving any warning message. Ideally it should give some warning message. How to get that message

Q2. id value needs to follow some REGEX pattern like [a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}.How to add this regex check. Also if I am providing id which does not follow this pattern should give some warning message? How to achieve it?

Q3. How to add enum for parameter?

Comment: There is no router class

Comment: Really sorry. I was updating the question yesterday.seems there something unusual happened. I will update it once again.  Is there any option to get the previous version of question??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate swagger documentation indicating that idField is an enumerated, you can use the schema property of the @Parameter annotation:

```
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "idType", schema = @Schema(implementation = EIndType.class))
```

Where EIndType is the enum where you define all the possible values:

```
public enum EIndType {
  SITEGEOID("siteGeoId"),
  SITERKST("siteRkst"),
  CITYGEOID("cityGeoId"),
  CITYRKST("cityRkst");

  private final String value;

  public String getValue() {
     return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have just added few more question. can you give your feedback on them?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer
Q1 answer

```
@Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.HEADER, name = "Authorization ",required = true,schema =@Schema(minLength = 1))
```

Q2 answer

```
@Parameter(in =  ParameterIn.QUERY, name = "id",required = true,schema = @Schema(minLength = 5,maxLength = 15,pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15}"))
```